# KLT Pyramid BoofCV

Tags: boofcv

I am working on an Android application that will use the KLT tracking algorithm. I have downloaded the Android sample provided by BoofCV's website and I have seen the code. However, I need it to work in the background on a different thread without the camera preview while in the front it will be a user interface of some sorts.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can make camera preview as small as 2x2 pixels effectively making it invisible while still receiving image frames in onPreviewFrame() - that's the way it's done in a BoofCV example application I've found